# I'm looking for a Sci-Fi book by my memoir

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a sci-fi book that I've read long ago and its plot was like:

The interplanetary Empire is ruled by some smart 'scientists' - people who write some kind of a code. They predicted that some hard times are coming and they might last for 10000 (ten thousand) years.

One of them (or small group of them) have analyzed the situation and the code and prepared a proposal for the code change (they knew the system and were passing knowledge about it over generations) and that change should have protected the Empire from being falling apart, neutralize the negative impact of the hard time and shrink the hard times to only 1000 (a thousand) years.

The change was not perfect and should have been adjusted by the future generations of the 'scientists-keepers'.

Comment: Isaac Asimov's *Foundation*; the "code" is psychohistory.

Comment: DawidW many thanks;)) that's what I've been looking for!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This sounds like Isasc Asimov's *[Foundation Trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundation_(Asimov_novel))*.

> The story begins on Trantor, the capital of the 12,000-year-old Galactic Empire, a powerful but slowly decaying empire. Hari Seldon, a mathematician and psychologist, has developed psychohistory, a new field of science and psychology that equates all possibilities in large societies to mathematics, allowing for the prediction of future events.
>
> By means of psychohistory, Seldon has discovered the declining nature of the Empire, angering the aristocratic members of the Committee of Public Safety, the de facto rulers of the Empire. The Committee considers Seldon's views and statements treasonous, and he is arrested along with young mathematician Gaal Dornick, who has arrived on Trantor to meet Seldon. Seldon is tried by the Committee and defends his beliefs, explaining his theories and predictions, including his belief that the Empire will collapse in 300 years and enter a 30,000-year dark age. He informs the Committee that an alternative to this future is attainable, and explains to them that creating a compendium of all human knowledge, the Encyclopedia Galactica, would not avert the inevitable fall of the Empire but would reduce the dark age to one millennium.
>
> The skeptical Committee, not wanting to make Seldon a martyr, offers him exile to a remote world, Terminus, with others who could help him create the Encyclopedia. He accepts their offer, prepares for the departure of the "Encyclopedists" and receives an imperial decree officially acknowledging his actions. Seldon informs Dornick that despite the Empire believing they won by exiling Seldon the outcome was exactly what he had hoped would happen. Terminus would be the home of the first Foundation while a second would be established "at Star's End." Seldon further announces he's dying and implores Dornick to become a leader in the new Foundation.

Comment: Thank you, FuzzyBoots;) That's what I've been looking for!